# Display dictionary in a specific format in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a dictionary dict1, if I display it with puts, that is

```
puts $dict1
```

then I get a result in the following format:

```
key1 value1 key2 value2 ...
```

I would like to display it in the follwoing format:

```
|key1 value1| |key2 value2| |key3 value3| ...
```

Is this possible? If yes, how? I couldn't find anything similar in my internet search.

If possible, I would like to avoid a proc and use a code as short as possible. Maybe something like

```
[format ...]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
set output {}
dict for {k v} $dict1 {
    lappend output "|$k $v|"
}
puts [join $output]
```

If you want it shorter, you can grit your teeth and put it in a proc that can be called wherever you need it.

Comment: Or to squeeze this a little tighter: `dict for {k v} $dict1 {puts -nonewline "|$k $v| "}`

Comment: Thank you! It works! The length of your code is good. It is short and immediately understandable. Thanks again!!

Comment: I'd prefer `puts [join [lmap {k v} $dict1 {string cat "|$k $v|"}] " "]`

Comment: @mrcalvin I don't like mixing dict and list commands

Comment: Although a dict **_is_** a list, I agree

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a slightly different approach: let Tcl add some quoting into the output to avoid ambiguity:

```
% set d [dict create "key1" "foo bar" "key1 foo" bar]

% dict for {k v} $d {puts [format {|%s %s|} $k $v]}
|key1 foo bar|
|key1 foo bar|

% dict for {k v} $d {puts "|[list $k $v]|"}
|key1 {foo bar}|
|{key1 foo} bar|
```